# jquery validation message

Tags: jquery, validation, input, message

i have 3 form input text for phone number.
currently i am validating each input text for a digit.

i have an input message for each individual input text.
instead of doing this:

```
phone1: {
        required: true,
        maxlength: 3,
        digits: true

},  
phone2: {
        required: true,
        maxlength: 3,
        digits: true

},
phone3: {
        required: true,
        maxlength: 4,
        digits: true

}

phone1:"enter value!.",
    phone2:"enter value!.",
    phone3:"enter value!."
```

i will like to only show one single message for all three fields. right now, i have 3 messages displaying on the screen. is there a way to only show just one until the user completes all required fields.

```
phone1,phone2,phone3:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use groups along with a custom errorPlacement function.

see here: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions under the heading "groups"

Answer (score 0):

You may want to set the `onfocusout` to false and `onsubmit` to true so that all validations are done at the time of submit.

If you are talking about having one single message irrespective of which one fails. You may setup a validation rule that validates all of them but marks just one of the fields to be invalid (e.g. Phone1).